# Is it possible to convert an HDMI signal to USB-C (Thunderbolt)

Tags: hdmi, usb-c

I have an LG UltraFine monitor that only accepts USB-C and I believe is generally marketed for Mac products.  Now working at home I would like to use the monitor with my work laptop.  The laptop dock only has HDMI outputs.  I have searched around, but I haven't found any products that go from HDMI to USB-C (which is Thunderbolt, basically, I think).  Do these type of adapters exist?

Thanks.

Edit: specs from the product page

USB 3 downstream (USB-C) Thunderbolt 3 Yes(x1), 5K@60Hz, USB-C

Comment: Do you want HDMI to Thunderbolt or HDMI to Type-C; Type-C isn't always Thunderbolt so saying it's "basically Thunderbolt" isn't an accurate statement

Comment: why not try a male usb-c to female hdmi adapter? at worst you're out $10-$20 and own an adapter you may end up using anyhow; at best it works.